# Migrating MongoDB fields with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, migration, mongoengine

So, I have two Documents in MongoDB modelled in MongoEngine (classic relational database example)

```
class Person(Document)
    name = StringField()

class Address(Document)
    person = ReferenceField(Person)
    city = StringField()
```

One person can have multiple addresses. I would like to migrate these models such that this becomes the new schema:

```
class Address(Document)
    city = StringField()

class Person(Document)
    name = StringField()
    address = ListField(ReferenceField(Address))
```

This involves both setting and unsetting fields on the two schema's and on top of that making sure that the old `Address` entries are migrated into the correct `Person` address list.

In my mind it would go something like this:

1. Set field to `Person`
2. For each `Address` add it to the correct `Person` by appending the `ListField`
3. Unset field from `Address`

This seems like a trivial example with an easy enough solution although the implementation for mongoengine has eluded me for some time now.
By changing the classes in python the server crashes complaining that `fields cannot be resolved`. Also reordering the classes is an issue since class dependency on eachother switches. On top of that collections in MongoDB need to be updated.

I remember SQLAlchemy has good migration support but I haven't found anything similar to this for Flask + MongoEngine.

Anyone know a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb does not have relationship like sqlalchemy so what about something like this:

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()
    address = ListField(DocumentField(Address))

city1 = Address(city='City1')
session.save(ad)
city2 = Address(city='City2')
session.save(city2)
person = Person(name='Ali', address=[city1, city2])
session.save(person)
```